# How to load a child object in appsetting.json (asp.net core)

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm writing a little Action Filter for an ASP.NET Core web API project.  The filter is for testing the associated UI for error handling.  It will throw an error if a specific verb and method is invoked.  The filter isn't a problem.  The problem is the appsettings.configuration.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
appsettings.development.json

```
"FaultTesting": {
    "FaultRequests": false,
    "SlowRequests": 0,
    "FaultCalls": [
      {
        "Path": "/api/usercontext",
        "Verbs": "get,put,delete"
      },
      {
        "Path": "/api/cafeteriaaccounts",
        "Verbs": "get"
      }
    ]
  }
```

These are my c# types to hold the configuration:

```
 public class FaultTestingOptions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// If true, checks FaultCalls for a path and verb to match.
        /// </summary>
        public bool FaultRequests { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of milliseconds to delay the response.
        /// </summary>
        public int SlowRequests { get; set; }

        public FaultCall[] FaultCalls { get; set; }

    }
    public class FaultCall
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string Verbs { get; set; }
    }
```

Add what I'm doing in startup:

```
            services.AddMvc(config =>
                {
...
FaultTestingFilter(Options.Create(GetFaultTestingOptions())));
...
                });

private FaultTestingOptions GetFaultTestingOptions()
{
    var options = new FaultTestingOptions
    {
        FaultRequests = Configuration["FaultTesting:FaultRequests"].ToBoolean(),
        SlowRequests = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["FaultTesting:SlowRequests"])
    };

    var calls = Configuration.GetSection("FaultTesting:FaultCalls")
        .GetChildren()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToArray();

    var fooie = Configuration["FaultTesting:FaultCalls"];


    //options.FaultCalls = calls.Select(c => new FaultCall { Path = c, Verbs = c.Value });

    return options;
}
```

"calls" is an array of two nulls, fooie is null.

What's the right approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better option is to bind `TOption` in `ConfigServices` method and then inject it to you filer. It work same as default model binder work, you did not need to manually read and set values.

ConfigureServices Method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<FaultTestingOptions>(option => Configuration.GetSection("FaultTesting").Bind(option));
    // Add framework services.

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Injecting in filter:

```
private readonly IOptions<FaultTestingOptions> config;

public FaultTestingFilter(IOptions<FaultTestingOptions> config)
{
    this.config = config;
}
```

Accessing the properties.

```
var SlowRequests= config.Value.SlowRequests;
var FaultCalls= config.Value.FaultCalls;
```